# How to manipulate data returned from Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying take a table of data returned from invoke-restmethod and insert it into a database. I am struggling with being able to select specific data columns.

When I use the Invoke-RestMethod I get data returned in the format below.

**Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4

data,aaa,bbb,ccc

data,ddd,eee,fff

data,ggg,hhh,iii**

However I cannot use Select or expandproperty to only grab specific rows. IE the commands below.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method Get -Headers $headers 
$response | Select col1, col2 | Sort-Object -property col2 -Descending
```

I have also tried to out-file the data however it looks like it is joining it all as one string.

**Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4data,aaa,bbb,cccdata,ddd,eee,fffdata,ggg,hhh,iii**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the data come back in JSON format? Can you edit your question to show exactly what format the Invoke-RestMethod gives you? It should return JSON.

Answer (score 1):

In order **to convert text containing CSV data to custom objects** (of type `[pscustomobject]`) that reflect the CSV data rows and whose properties represent the column values, **use the [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) cmdlet.**

The resulting objects can then be used with cmdlets such as `Select-Object` - for extraction of properties of interest - and `Sort-Object`.

Here's a simplified example:

```
# Simulate the outcome of your Invoke-RestMethod call with a here-string:
$response = @'
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
data,aaa,bbb,ccc
data,ddd,eee,fff
data,ggg,hhh,iii
'@

$response | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object Col1, Col2 | Sort-Object Col2 -Descending
```

The above yields the following 3 `[pscustomobject]` instances, sorted in descending order by their `.Col2` property values:

```
Col1 Col2
---- ----
data ggg
data ddd
data aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're invoking a REST API call, the data coming back *could* be in JSON format. You can convert it as follows:

```
$jsonResponse = Inovke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers
$newObject = $jsonResponse | ConvertFrom-Json
```

-or

```
$newObject = $Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This means `$jsonResponse` is:

```
{
    "FirstName" : "Tom",
    "LastName" : "Crooze"
}
```

Converting to `newObject` it would look like this:

```
FirstName      LastName
---------      --------
      Tom        Crooze
```

Comment: While JSON as a response format is common, REST APIs aren't restricted to it, and there are APIs that do return `text/csv` data.